# manage sub directories permission in s3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I have different brands and we create a sub directory for each of them on S3. I want to give permission to each brands user on it's own directory. Users will put files directly on his directory and can not access to others directory. If i give them the access key and secret it can access hole directory. So i am thinking to create an sftp connection for each user to have access his own directory. I have create an sftp connection through aws web interface and it works. Now question is how can i create sftp connection in my app when i create sub directory for a brand. I am working in PHP with Laravel framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing each brand has it's own set of access and secret keys? In that case you can limit access using IAM and bucket policies. Here is a blog post on how to do that : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/